# Android SMSManager onReceive also receiving push messages

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm developing an app that listens to incoming SMS. Everything is working fine, but the problem is in `onReceive()` method of Broadcast receiver, it is also receiving the SIM card's push (Class 0) messages (like balance info / SMS remaining, etc which comes as pop up after sending an SMS or making a call).

I want to handle only the SMS messages in that method. Is there any check by which I can distinguish between these messages in `onReceive()`?

Comment: use action in your intent filter of broadcast receiver and check the action while receiving message

Comment: action is `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` in both the cases as I've set this action only in Manifest in the receiver

Comment: If they are indeed coming through as class zero SMS, the `SmsMessage` class has [the `getMessageClass()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage#getMessageClass()) that I believe you can check to see if it's `== SmsMessage.MessageClass.CLASS_0`.